# Update works only for last method call

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a quite simple `UPDATE` statement and it works correctly but for **only** one call. I have few projects (FAIs) in database and I want to change responsible person.

If I want to change two or more responsibles it only changes the responsible person for the last project. I don't have any error messages. All values are correctly send to update query but the query just does not send it to the database.

```
public void updateFaiUBazu(string orderNumber, FAI fai, int serialNumber)
{
    konekcija.Open();
    MessageBox.Show(fai.Reviewer);
    komanda = new SqlCommand("
        update FAI set 
            AircraftFK = @AircraftFK, GlassFK = @GlassFK, PartNumber = @PartNumber, 
            SerialNumber = @SerialNumber, ReportNumber = @ReportNumber, 
            Reviewer = @Reviewer, Comment = @Comment, DateTime = @DateTime, 
            Iges = @Iges, IgesName = @IgesName, Status = @Status 
            where 
                 AircraftFK = " + fai.AircraftFK1 + 
                 " and GlassFK = " + fai.GlassFK1 +
                 " and SerialNumber = " + serialNumber, 
         konekcija);
    try
    {
        komanda.Parameters.Clear();
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AircraftFK", fai.AircraftFK1);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlassFK", fai.GlassFK1);
        // komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumberFK", fai[i].OrderNumerFK);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", fai.PartNumber);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", fai.SerialNumber);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportNumber", fai.ReportNumber);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reviewer", fai.Reviewer);
        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", fai.Comment);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", fai.DateAndTime);  

        if (fai.IgesFile.Length != 0)
        {
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iges", fai.IgesFile);
        }
        else
        {
            komanda.Parameters.Add("@Iges", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
            komanda.Parameters["@Iges"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fai.IgesName))
        {
            komanda.Parameters.Add("@IgesName", fai.IgesName).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IgesName", fai.IgesName);
        }

        komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Not Tested");

        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    konekcija.Close();
}
```

Could that be some limitation with SqlServer update statement?

Comment: How do you call this function? Also, try logging the queries with parameters passed, most likely there are some mistakes.

Comment: Have you stepped through it to see if conditional logic is blocking your query from being executed?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but DateTime is the name of a DataType in SqlServer. Perhaps it is better to put square brackets around the Field Name in the sql text

Comment: I am calling it with: Broker br = Broker.dajInstancu();
            br.updateFaiUBazu(orderNumber, fai, serialNumber);
Broker opens the connection to database.
It looks like I don't have any errors not in SQL and not in C# because it works with all other situations. It just doesn't work for multiple calls of update statement

Comment: By adding square brackets do you mean adding brackets as [DateTime = @DateTime] or something else? Thank you in advance. Sorry for probably dummy questions but I'm not very familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

Follow a couple of steps to get to your problem.

1. Log yout update queries. JUst after you have created it. This will tell you if your updates are really executed when you are calling them from a loop.
2. If all your updates are logged, copy them to SSMS query window and execute them one by one in sequence. This would give you corect idea if there is anything wong with way queries are getting formed, or of there is any specific value in one of the parameters which is causing the problem. This will also help you identify if the problem specified by @Steve above exists.